# How to rebase git pull request and auto close it on Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, rebase, pull-request

I maintain a repository and a user submitted several pull requests. I want to rebase them for a clear history. What I do works fine if the pull request I merge is fully up to date with my repository:

```
git remote add <username> <URL>
git fetch <username>
git checkout -b <pull-request-branch> <username>/<pull-request-branch>
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only <pull-request-branch>
git push origin master
git branch -d <pull-request-branch>
```

But when pull request branch is not up to date with my repository this pull request doesn't get closed after I push to origin and deleting branch doesn't work giving error:

> warning: not deleting branch 'kb8' that is not yet merged to
>            'refs/remotes/benuser/kb8', even though it is merged to HEAD. error: The branch 'kb8' is not fully merged. If you are sure you want
>   to delete it, run 'git branch -D kb8'.

From what I read I need to force push this branch first to the username repository but I decided to firstly ask here before doing dangerous things. So how do I properly rebase pull request which isn't fully up to date with my repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so for my needs forcing a push works fine and closes pull request. After doing

```
git rebase master
```

I need to do

```
git push --force <username> <pull-request-branch>
```

And after this I can safely merge this branch into master.

Comment: I'd replace your first command with "git fetch; git rebase origin/master".